# How to animate using Path with Storyboard in C#

Tags: c#, storyboard

So, I am trying to move my rectangular boxes around a grid like this -

[image]

For this, I am using a Story board.

I am using DoubleAnimation to move the boxes on X-Axis and Y-Axis in one of my Class. I am calling this class from MainWindow class. But, for every box, and for every turn, I have to create a new Double animation, assign the offset values, the start time, the duration etc. like this -

```
        //Code to move Boxes 1-4 to first grid point in their path
        TranslateTransform moveTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        moveTransform.X = 0;
        moveTransform.Y = 0;
        x.RenderTransform = moveTransform;


        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();


        DoubleAnimation Move1= new DoubleAnimation();

        Move1.From = 0;
        Move1.To = xPosition; // calculate correct offset here
        Move1.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(hops));
        if (x==Box2)
        {
            Move1.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);//For Box 2, the first move will be across Y-Axis and hence X-Axis move will be delayed by 5 seconds.
        }
        else
        {
            Move1.BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        Storyboard.SetTarget(Move1, x);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Move1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(X)"));
        s.Children.Add(Move1);
```

I know there is a way to define the path to reach the destination from source, but I am not sure how to do it? Also, I am not sure if what I am doing here is the optimal way.

So, my question is -

**What is the better way to do this? How can we define paths for animation?**

I am a newbie to C# so please do not mind if this sounds silly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it without using path.

For every move, I created a new double animation.

So for Left - Down - Right movement, I created 3 double animations with

X-Axis, Y-Axis and X-Axis again.